# How does the Flying Dagger Swarm's aura work?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

The Flying Dagger Swarm (dungeon magazine #195, pag 18) aura states:

> Aura 1 - any enemy that starts his turn in the aura takes ongoing 5 damage (save ends). If that enemy is already taking untyped ongoing damage, that damage increases by 5.
>   (no errata or FAQs published)

Three questions:

- The aura gives you ongoing 5 damage at the start of your turn. But, ongoing 5 damage also gets triggered at the start of your turn. If a PC starts his turn in the aura, does he take the ongoing damage right away in that turn or does he take the damage starting the following turn?
- if a PC starts his turn in the aura of two Flying Dagger Swarms, does he take 5 ongoing or does he take 10 ongoing from the auras overlapping?
- if a PC starts his turn in the aura and is already taking ongoing damage, does he take the original ongoing damage or the one increased by the aura in that turn?

Comment: I'm not sure what the distinction you are trying to make in your first question is. If the PC starts their turn in the aura, then they take damage.

Comment: @firedraco It's because the aura doesn't give you damage directly, it gives you ongoing 5 damage. Ongoing damage in turn gets applied at the start of the turn — and your turn is starting now, so have you skipped the ongoing damage trigger this turn or do you start taking damage right away?

Comment: Exactly what dopplegreener said, also i added another question point on interactions with pre existing ongoing damage

Comment: Can you tell us where the Flying Dagger Swarm was published? It's possible that errata was published for it.

Comment: I checked woth the compiled FAQs and erratas and nothing has been published, unless there's a source of those i don't lnow about

Comment: I  might suggest posting these distinct questions separately, as they are distinct, separate questions with answers that will likely be unrelated to one another. It would help you to get a more focused answer for each question and keep the site that much more organized!

Comment: @MrSpudtastic All 3 questions are about the same specific monster ability and how it interacts with the rules. We allow multiple questions in the same post if they are sufficiently focused on the same topic, which is the case here.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Thank you for the clarification, I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **They would not take 5 damage until their next turn**

The start of turn would trigger the:

> If you are taking ongoing damage, increase it by 5, otherwise take ongoing 5.

effect, but then it is done. The start of turn trigger is a single instant in time that can trigger multiple effects, not a phase of time that is repeatedly checked for changes and new effects after each effect is resolved.

2) **They would be taking 10 ongoing**

This is treated as 2 effects happening in sequence; since they are the same the order does no matter, but they are both essentially:

> If you are taking ongoing damage, increase it by 5, otherwise take ongoing 5.

Therefore, we apply the first effect, which would give the PC ongoing 5, then apply the second, which would see the ongoing 5 and increase it by 5 to ongoing 10.

3) **It depends on the controller of the character**

As per the Rules Compendium, if multiple effects are occurring at the same time, the acting player can choose the ordering of the effects. Hence it depends on the order they choose; they can choose to either increase the ongoing damage first, then take the ongoing damage, or take the ongoing damage first, then increase it.

Comment: I am almost certain I saw this in the Rules Compendium somewhere but I don't have it with me right now...if someone can prove it incorrect before I get to checking, post a comment and I'll go ahead and delete this answer.

Comment: Whoops! Focused too much on that one! I added resolutions for the other scenarios now as well.

Comment: Sounds right, i scoured the rules compendium and it looks like those are the correct interpretations. Than you.